# Many chrome processes scheduled on windows startup

Tags: google-chrome, boot, windows-8.1, process

When going through my list of startup programs, I found that expanding chrome shows up a huge list of chrome processes!
[image: Startup list showing chrome processes]

What is especially striking is that even while **browsing** there are only **10** processes in the process detail list while there are **19** scheduled to **startup** in the startup list!

[image: Chrome process list (while browsing)]

I am aware about the fact that chrome takes multi-threading to new heights by spawning processes representing each tab, extension, and other background services, etc but is this true for even the windows startup?
**Ultimately, Is it normal for chrome to schedule a separate process for each of its modules on windows startup?**
If not is there any remedy besides entirely disabling the chrome startup? Since I would like to selectively have certain modules startup on boot though.

**Other relevant information:**

- OS: Windows 8.1 x64
- Device: Toshiba Satellite
- Chrome Version: 39.0.2171.65 m
  -

Comment: If you are worried disable them. I use Chrome often, I have no startup entry for Chrome, on any of my machines.

Comment: @Ramhound I would like to know that there are no, feasible alternatives before coming to that conclusion though. There are particular extensions that I would like to have startup like the hangouts extension, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome has its own task manager. You can manage which plugin is enabled/disabled. You can find it on here:

> [image: chrome task manager]

- Click "Customize and control Google Chrome" icon on the top-right
- Select "More tools"
- Click "Task manager" (or use shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>)

I also recommend you to turn off "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" under Advanced Settings.

> [image: chrome background apps]

You may also check the `chrome://apps/` section and delete unnecessary apps, because this also can be a possible reason for your problem.

Comment: There are only 10 processes in the chrome task manager but 19 scheduled for startup. Whats worse is that they all have startup impact "High"! I have selected 6 extensions that I want enabled. What is going on? Why are the others scheduled? Also your "this" link is broken.

Comment: Link is now fix it, now please view it, becouser I belive you can find the missing tasks.
If you can't find it, please view also the application section in chrome://apps/

Comment: Yes! removing some unwanted apps from chrome://apps (which were not visible in the task manager) did reduce the startup from 19 to 12! Thanks! Please include it in your answer for me to accept it. Checking the chrome task manager wasn't much help to me though. Everything it showed was important.

Comment: Edit, added, I happy for your problem is solved :)